# SQL to check how many sites a user is a member of

Tags: multisite, user-meta, sql

I have a multisite installation and I'm working on creating a reporting plugin. One of the things that I would like to do is show the number of sites a user is a member of.

Right now, I'm using something like this in my SQL:

```
JOIN `wp_usermeta` m ON m.user_id = u.ID AND ( `meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities' OR `meta_key` LIKE 'wp_%_capabilities' )
```

I'm not comfortable using the `%` wildcard in that syntax. It could easily end up selecting any meta value that ends in *capabilities*.

Besides the alternative (listing each site with an `AND` in the subquery) - is there a way to select just wp_##_capabilities in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the [`get_blogs_of_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blogs_of_user) function:

```
echo count( get_blogs_of_user( $user_ID ) );
```

instead of your custom SQL query.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not just trying to get a list of blogs - there are other things in the SQL query that need to be evaluated.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `meta_key REGEXP '^wp([_0-9]*)capabilities$'` or  `meta_key REGEXP '^wp_{0,1}[0-9]*_{0,1}capabilities$'` ? Not sure how effective that would be.

Comment: Just saw the update. This seems to work well. I'll do a bit of testing with it. Of course a regular expression would cover it!

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with birgire's comment (huge thanks), I put together a relatively simple regular expression that *seems* to be solid:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key REGEXP('^wp_([[:digit]]+_)?capabilities$')
```

The prefix can be easily added / changed without breaking the expression. It also requires at least 1 number and an underscore for any multisite comparisons. For the custom query I can use it thus:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.user_email, u.user_login, COUNT(meta_key)
FROM `wp_users` u
JOIN `wp_usermeta` um ON um.user_id = u.ID AND um.meta_key REGEXP('^wp_([[:digit]]+_)?capabilities$')
GROUP BY u.ID
```

This shows me how many sites a user is registered with and can be built on.

Comment: I'd rewrite the Regex to `^wp_([\d]+?_)?capabilities$` to use the `\d` for digits and make that part lazy/non-greedy.

Comment: I tried `\d` alone but mySQL wasn't happy about it at all. I'll check out your extra tags though and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: That only works, [as you can see in this cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/), for normal Regex (and I assumed that you prepared your statement and the `REGEXP(%s)` was just injected. You can use `[:digit:]` in MySQL.

Comment: Ah, I see that the POSIX syntax is the way to go. I've updated my answer with the digits class, but the following question mark in your original comment causes a *repitition-operator* error. I've always managed to avoid mySQL regular expressions to now - so thank you for enlightening me.