# Any number in meta key (wp query)

Tags: wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I have such a query. The field modules_%_text is advanced custom fields flexible field where % should stand for ANY ROW number, it seams that it should work like that, however it's not. What i'm doing wrong? Maybe % doesn't stand for any number or? If i'm entering modules_0_text i'm getting correct field.

```
...

'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
array(
'key' => 'price',
'value' => $_GET['searchword'],
'compare' => 'LIKE'
),
array(
'key' => 'modules_%_text',
'value' => $_GET['searchword'],
'compare' => 'LIKE'
)

...
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Here is my args:

$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'custompost',
  'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
    array('key' => 'modules_%_text','value' => $_GET['from'],'compare' => 'LIKE'),
    array('key' => 'modules_%_images','value' => $_GET['to'],'compare' => 'LIKE')
   )    
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `LIKE` on the `meta_key` to support the SQL `%` pattern. The `compare` attribute only applies to the meta value.

Instead you could try to filter it with:

```
/**
 * Match any numbers in given a meta-key for WP_Query
 *
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177331/26350
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where )
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Replace the following meta key search:
    $find = $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key = 'modules_%_text'";

    // with a LIKE search:
    //$to = $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key LIKE 'modules_%_text'";

    // or a REGEXP search:
    $to   = $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key REGEXP '^modules_[0-9]+_text$'";

    // Replace:
    if( false !== stripos( $where, $find ) )    
        $where = str_ireplace( $find, $to, $where );

    return $where;
} );
```

This should modify your meta key search from:

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'modules_%_text'
```

to

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key  LIKE 'modules_%_text'
```

or if you must only match numbers in the meta key:

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key  REGEXP '^modules_[0-9]+_text$'
```

PS: [Here's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/176158/26350) another similar question that was posted recently.

### Update:

Answering the comment regarding multiple replacements:

```
/**
 * Match any numbers in given array of meta-keys for WP_Query
 *
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177331/26350
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where )
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Replace the following meta keys:
    $a_find = [ 
        $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key = 'modules_%_text'",
        $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key = 'modules_%_images'"
    ];

    // with a LIKE search:
    //$a_to = [
    //    $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key LIKE 'modules_%_text'",
    //    $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key LIKE 'modules_%_images'"
    //];

    // or a REGEXP search:
    $a_to   = [
        $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key REGEXP '^modules_[0-9]+_text$'",
        $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_key REGEXP '^modules_[0-9]+_images$'"
    ];

    // Replace:
    return str_ireplace( $a_find, $a_to, $where );

} );
```

where `$a_find` and `$a_to` are arrays of equal size.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help! I'm getting this after copying that code to my functions.php -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in 146 line, which is: ! is_admin() && add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where )

Comment: I think you're using very old version of PHP, since closure is supported by PHP version 5.3+. What's your PHP version?

Comment: I'm using version 5.2 and at the moment I can't change to newer as where are some older projects on server. I will try it later somehow. or it could be easily changed to support 5.2?

Comment: [Here's the PHP 5.2+ version](https://gist.github.com/birgire/1aa235e0b800b9a2b6f7)

Comment: Birgire - thank you very much :) Everything works like i wanted. Many thanks for your help. Only in your code on github  line 27 should be NOT " } ); " BUT " }; "

Comment: maybe you could help me with this code again. I need to add another meta key. What i should do that this code would work both with 'modules_%_text' and 'modules_%_images'? Thank you in advance :) @birgire

Comment: Hi @MIC please check the updated answer. If it solved your problem, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to close the question, thanks.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. It didn't worked on first try, but switching from PHP 5.3 -> 5.4 made it to work :) Thanks again. You are absolutely awesome. Beer on me if I ever be in Iceland sometime :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you. I forgot to mention the PHP 5.4+ part, but I used `[]` notation instead of `array()` and an *anonymous function* that's supported in PHP 5.3+. Cheers ;-) @MIC

Comment: need your help again :) The problem is that it doesn't work with relation "AND". If i set it to "LIKE" everything works but as soon as i'm switching to AND it shows no results. Here is query code part i'm using:
'relation' => 'AND',
 array('key' => 'modules_%_text','value' => $_GET['from'],'compare' => 'LIKE'),
    array('key' => 'modules_%_images','value' => $_GET['to'],'compare' => 'LIKE')
   )

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: @MIC that shouldn't be a problem, are you sure your constrictions aren't just too restrict? ;-)

Comment: i have updated my first comment what args i use for WP. It seems ok, however it shows 0 results and i'm sure that it should get back some posts.

Comment: aha, you must use `=` in your compare attribute for the filter to kick-in. That's how we started, but you could be modify that to your needs. @MIC

Comment: i have changed LIKE to = for both compare parameters, but nothing changed. Maybe you got any idea :) i actually can solve it by using only one parameter and when manipulate with php, but it would be great to have working query for two  conditions :)

Comment: Strange, how does the generated SQL look like? @MIC